# Why is SIP keeping me from using `dtruss` on an executable outside its protected folders?

Tags: sip, dtrace

I'm trying to run the following command on OS X El Capitan (10.11.4):

```
sudo dtruss /usr/local/bin/mix phoenix.server
```

It fails, saying:

> dtrace: failed to execute /usr/local/bin/mix: dtrace cannot control executables signed with restricted entitlements

`mix` is an executable I installed with Homebrew. `/usr/local/bin/mix` is actually a symlink, but it points to a file nested under `/usr/local/Cellar`.

The [official statement on SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) says that `/usr/local` is writable for installers (unlike `/usr/` generally). It doesn't say whether SIP allows tracing programs there, but given that I installed this myself, it seems reasonable to be able to trace it.

Is there something I can do to allow tracing this program? Ideas I have:

- Disable SIP entirely (seems heavy-handed)

  - Update: I read that one can [disable parts of SIP selectively](http://internals.exposed/blog/dtrace-vs-sip.html), but as a first step, I [completely disabled it](http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html). `csrutil status` now reports `System Integrity Protection status: disabled.`. But my original command still fails with the same error. :(
- Make Homebrew install everything to a folder under `~` (seems messy)

  - Update: pretty sure this [would be a bad idea](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-prefer-i-install-to-usrlocal)
- Ignore Homebrew and compile `mix` from source into `~`, then dtruss the new executable

  - Update: same failure. **This one really makes no sense to me**. SIP is turned off, the executable isn't "signed" since I compiled it myself, and it's not in a restricted location. :P
- Install Linux in a VM. (seriously? do I have to do this?)

Comment: What happens if you either copy the mix binary to a place below `~` or create a hard link?

Comment: @patrix I copied it to `~`, and while `mix` can run from there, trying to `dtruss` it gives the same error.

Comment: Note - my particular use case was to watch what files a process accessed. `sudo fs_usage > some_file` and later grepping for the process of interest worked for that. But I still don't understand why my original command doesn't work. I'm root and I explicitly asked for the sharp scissors.